# how to find mean in rows of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average, mean

df:

```
 A B  C D
 1 2  3 la
 0 1 -1 na
```

How to find mean each row like that?:

```
 A B  C  D  mean
 1 2  3  la    2
 0 1 -1  na    0
```

I try, but not the case(:

```
 some_col = [A,B,C]
 for col in some_col:
    df['mean'] = [np.mean([x, y]) for x, y in zip(df[col], df['mean'])]
```

Comment: `df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)` (but the mean of `0, 1, -1` is `0`, not `1`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try this:

```
df.mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: forgot to add, that df can include different type of data, as a parameter i get list of names columns in which mean must be found? found) thanks
df[list].mean(axis=1)

Comment: `df.mean(axis=1)` will actually work and ignore the column (`'D'`) with strings. However, you will get a warning that this behaviour is deprecated and will raise TypeError in the future, so best to avoid this. If you have a list like `lst_cols = ['A','B','C']`, use `df[lst_cols].mean(axis=1)` afterwards. Alternatively, if you are happy to select *all* numeric columns, you could use `df.select_dtypes(include='number').mean(axis=1)`.