# Apply custom function to define new dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with six columns, that define a given individual:

1. `Age`,
2. `Gender`,
3. `Education Level`,
4. `Job Title`,
5. `Years of Experience`,
6. `Salary`.

Additionally, I have **four skillset columns**, each with skill levels graded out of 10:

1. `Programming skills`,
2. `Microsoft Office`,
3. `Web development`,
4. `Sales management`

I want to add a new column representing the average skill level for each individual. I'm looking for a way to:

- calculate the average skill level based on the values in the skill set columns
- then add this calculated average as a new column.

Here's a sample of my DataFrame and the code I've tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Age': [30, 25, 35],
    'Gender': ['Male', 'Female', 'Male'],
    'Education Level': ['Bachelor', 'Master', 'Ph.D.'],
    'Job Title': ['Engineer', 'Manager', 'Analyst'],
    'Years of Experience': [5, 8, 3],
    'Salary': [60000, 80000, 55000],
    'Programming skills': [8, 7, 6],
    'Microsoft Office': [9, 8, 7],
    'Web development': [6, 5, 7],
    'Sales management': [7, 8, 6]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Calculate and add the average skill level column here
```

Comment: What did you try? There are lots of questions about adding/computing new columns to a dataframe and it’s no clear why this question wouldn’t  be answered by one of themn

Comment: Every skillset column markdown out of 10 expecting 'salary' and 'job title' like 7, 8 or 9

Comment: Are you trying to make the new column based conditionally on what is in the other columns?

Comment: I have made conditions like this when salary > 60000 and 'Job Title' == 'Data Analyst', The 'Programing Skills' column markdown out of 10 that is 7, 8 or 9 anything

Comment: New answer based on your above comment, kindly review.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on what you're looking for but in general it would look something like this

```
df['new_column'] = values
```

Where values is a list or array and must be the same length of your dataframe

Comment: dataset.loc[dataset['Job Title'] == 'Data Analyst', 'Programming skills'] = 08
I have error leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers

Comment: That would be for adding hardcoded values. Regarding the error @PijushGhorai, adding 08 is not like adding 8. 08 is raising the leading zeroes error.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a new column as the average of previous columns has been answered elsewhere. In your case it would look like this:

```py
# Select columns to average
skillset_columns = ['Programming skills','Microsoft Office','Web development','Sales management']

# Define the new column
df['mean skill'] = df[skillset_columns].mean(axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
   Age  Gender Education Level Job Title  Years of Experience  Salary  Programming skills  Microsoft Office  Web development  Sales management  mean skill
0   30    Male        Bachelor  Engineer                    5   60000                   8                 9                6                 7         7.5
1   25  Female          Master   Manager                    8   80000                   7                 8                5                 8         7.0
2   35    Male           Ph.D.   Analyst                    3   55000                   6                 7                7                 6         6.5
```

If that were your question, it would be a duplicate of [how to find mean in rows of dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72944650/12846804) and a literal application of the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html).

---

However, the following alternative may be more adapted to your needs, based on your not-so-clear comment "*I have made conditions like this when salary > 60000 and 'Job Title' == 'Data Analyst', The 'Programing Skills' column markdown out of 10 that is 7, 8 or 9 anything'.*"

```py
# 1. Define your custom row function for skill estimation
def skill_estimator(row):
    '''Your feature engineering formula to calculate mean skill for one individual'''
    
    # A first condition
    if (row['Salary'] >= 50000) and (row['Job Title'] == 'Analyst'):
        # why not some weighted average
        s = (row['Programming skills'] * 2 + row['Web development'])/3
    else:
        s=0
        
    # and so on and so forth
    
    return s

# 2. Apply it to every row, defining a new column:
df['mean skill'] = df.apply(skill_estimator, axis='columns')
```

... In which case your question is a duplicate of e.g. [How to apply a function to two columns of Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13331698/12846804) except you're applying function to more than 2 columns.

But to go further, your feature could be a weighted average with profile-dependent weights, e.g. give more importance to sales in case of profile "manager" and so on and so forth.